# How to apply a common route for multiple ASP.NET MVC controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a common base controller and a couple of inherited controller classes with similar routes applied to them. I want to apply the common part of the different routes to the base class. **Below is the bare minimum of my code:**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public abstract class CommonController : Controller
{
    // Some common code here
}

[Route("api/v1/BookLookup")]
public class BooksController : CommonController
{
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetAsync([FromBody]Dto1 filterParameters)
    {
        return await GetApiData(filterParameters);
    }
}

[Route("api/v1/MovieLookup")]
public class MoviesController : CommonController
{
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetAsync([FromBody]Dto1 filterParameters)
    {
        return await GetApiData(filterParameters);
    }
}
```

**I want to have something like the following:**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[Route("api/v1/")] // or any other attribute?
public abstract class CommonController : Controller
{
    // Some common code here
}

[Route("BookLookup")]
public class BooksController : CommonController
{
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetAsync([FromBody]Dto1 filterParameters)
    {
        return await GetApiData(filterParameters);
    }
}

[Route("MovieLookup")]
public class MoviesController : CommonController
{
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetAsync([FromBody]Dto1 filterParameters)
    {
        return await GetApiData(filterParameters);
    }
}
```

is this possible and if it is, how?

The project targets .NET Core 2.0 and the `Controller` class in the above example is ASP.NET Core MVC controller class, not Web API controller.

Comment: Can't you just create empty, let's say: `["api/v1/"] ApiV1Controller : CommonController`?

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `RouteAttribute` will not work with controller inheritance by default. However, to achieve your goal, you could create a custom [IControllerModelConvention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.icontrollermodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-2.0) to apply a rule that takes consideration of controller inheritance at startup-time.

To avoid mixing up with the default `[RouteAttribute]`, I create a custom `MyRoutePrefixAttribute` instead of using the default `[RouteAttribute]` (Feel free to use the `[RouteAttribute]` if you think this behavior should be overrided ):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class MyRoutePrefixAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyRoutePrefixAttribute(string prefix) { Prefix = prefix; }
    public string Prefix { get; }
}
```

And to lookup this `[MyRoutePrefixAttribute]` from the inheritance chain, I create a `RoutePrefixConvention` that will combine the prefixes recursively:

```
public class RoutePrefixConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        foreach (var selector in controller.Selectors)
        {
            var prefixes = GetPrefixes(controller.ControllerType);  // [prefix, parentPrefix, grandpaPrefix,...]
            if(prefixes.Count ==  0) continue;
            // combine these prefixes one by one
            var prefixRouteModels = prefixes.Select(p => new AttributeRouteModel(new RouteAttribute(p.Prefix)))
                .Aggregate( (acc , prefix)=> AttributeRouteModel.CombineAttributeRouteModel(prefix, acc));
            selector.AttributeRouteModel =  selector.AttributeRouteModel != null ?
                AttributeRouteModel.CombineAttributeRouteModel(prefixRouteModels, selector.AttributeRouteModel):
                selector.AttributeRouteModel = prefixRouteModels;
        }
    }

    private IList<MyRoutePrefixAttribute> GetPrefixes(Type controlerType)
    {
        var list = new List<MyRoutePrefixAttribute>();
        FindPrefixesRec(controlerType, ref list);
        list = list.Where(r => r!=null).ToList();
        return list;

        // find [MyRoutePrefixAttribute('...')] recursively 
        void FindPrefixesRec(Type type, ref List<MyRoutePrefixAttribute> results)
        {
            var prefix = type.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<MyRoutePrefixAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            results.Add(prefix);   // null is valid because it will seek prefix from parent recursively
            var parentType = type.BaseType;
            if(parentType == null) return;
            FindPrefixesRec(parentType, ref results);
        }
    }
}
```

this convention will NOT influence the performance: it only searches all the `[MyRoutePrefixAttribute]` attributes through the inheritance chain at startup time.

Finally, don't forget to add this convention within your startup:

```
services.AddMvc(opts =>
{
     opts.Conventions.Add(new RoutePrefixConvention());
});
```

Controller:

```
[MyRoutePrefix("api/v1")]
public class CommonController : Controller
{ 
}

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("MovieLookup")]
public class MoviesController : CommonController
{
    public string GetAsync()
    {
        return "MovieLookup";
    }
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

Hope this can help you.